# ALT+SysRq+REISUB hangs at "resetting" (without actually resetting/restarting)

Tags: kernel, sysrq

I'm trying <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>SysRq</kbd> + <kbd>REISUB</kbd> to see how it would be used to restart my system safely in case of emergency.

However, I find that <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>SysRq</kbd> + <kbd>REISUB</kbd> hangs at "resetting" (without actually resetting/restarting) in Maverick.

All other <kbd>SysRq</kbd> combinations appear to work correctly (i.e. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>SysRq</kbd> + <kbd>REISU</kbd>).

cat /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq returns 0. But I'm not sure it's relevant because <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>SysRq</kbd> certainly works.

What can I do to have "B" actually restart the system?

Comment: Do you see any console messages when you press those keys?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was saying, they appear to work correctly: after each key press (beginning with SysRq+E) I'm seeing status updates from the OS: that it synced the file systems and things like that. Even the last keypress SysRq+B appears to work (it says "... resetting") except for the fact that my laptop does not actually restart (as if the hardware does not receive the command required to reboot).

Comment: Maybe you have ACPI issues. Try booting with ``nolapic`` and ``acpi=off`` and ``acpi=bios``

Comment: No, SysRq handlers will sometimes shut off at the unmount, and a hard reset is safe.

Comment: Does SysRq+O (for Off) work? I used to have a system where that worked, but not reBoot, despite all my efforts.

Answer (score 1):

**Alt + SysRq +**

**R** - takes keyboard and mouse control from the X server. This can be useful if the X-Server crashed, you can change to a console and kill the X-Server or check the error log.
NOTE:- The documentation refers to this key's task as "Turns off keyboard raw mode and sets it to XLATE", but I suppose it's safe enough to assume that it takes back control from X.

**E** - sends SIGTERM to all processes except init. This means that an attempt is done to end the current processes except init, safely, e.g. saving a document.

**I** - sends SIGKILL to all processes except init. This means that all the processes except for init are killed, any data in processes that are killed will be lost.

**S** - writes all data from the disc cache to the hard-discs, it is a sync and is necessary to reduce the chances of data corruption.

**U** - remounts all mounted filesystems read-only. After using this key, you can reboot the system with Alt+SysRq+B without harming the system.

**B** - restarts the system without making steps to ensure that the conditions are good for a safe reboot, using this key alone is like doing a cold reboot.

---

Try without pressing **R** at begining of your sequence 
or just do it in another seq.. give a litle time between those keystrokes and do this..

Alt + SysRq + **R S E I U B**

and better you enable *Magic SysRq* by entering..

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
```

Comment: In my opinion, `R` and `I` are totally worthless for most people. Just do `E`, `S`, `U` and `B`. That gives well behaving apps possibility to save changes (`E`) and `SUB` will sync, umount and boot.